# What type of genetic changes occurs when ovaries or uterus are removed from female body?

Tags: human-genetics, surgery, gynecology

I saw so many women which have present dermoid cysts in their ovaries or uteruses. Doctors operate and mostly the ovaries and uterus can not be saved and the doctors remove the ovaries or uterus.

Which type of genetic changes occur in such type of women?

Answer (score 7):

welcome to biology stackexchange!

In the classical way we think of the body, there won't be a lot of genetic changes if the ovaries, uterus (or the testes for that matter) are removed from the body.

The main effect would be that the sex hormones that are produced in these organs would no longer be present and this would have a profound effect. So the broad answer might be 'no genetic effects but large **endocrine** changes'.  Endocrinology is the study of glands and their function in the body. Growing cysts, tumors as well as other effects seem like reasonable effects to see for such a drastic change in the body as removing the reproductive organs.

If I were hard pressed though probably this might end up with some small genetic effects compared to an individual who had never had the organs removed.  Mutations happen frequently in many of our tissues and also they respond to the environment to methylate the genome and modify it in non-genetic ways ( known as epigenetic effects).  This is purely conjecture but its also found that nearly everything has **some** effect on the cells.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

*Answer simplified to match OP level*

There are two different parts of biology in this question:

1. **Genetic** changes, only happen when the DNA changes (in a person's genes). But in general, this is fixed before your birth (when you are conceived), and what happens in your life does not change it any more.
   More accurately, genetics can change, or be changed, but not just by removal of a body part like this question asks.
2. **Removal of organs** like the ovaries and uterus will mean that hormones they produce, and actions they are involved in, may be reduced or stop.  That can change a persons life a lot, because hormones and other functions play a major role in our body. But it doesn't change the person's genes, or genetic makeup.

A way to think about this is, if a doctor had to remove your leg, or your tonsils, and then you had a child, your child would have the leg, or tonsils, even if you didn't. Because that is in your genes, and has not been changed.